# find which files were manually resolved on perforce integrate

Tags: perforce, integrate

I'm trying to find which files were manually resolved (either edited or ignored) on a 'integrate' changelist already submitted. I can find them in p4v using the 'revision graph' and checking the shape of the arrows but I'm searching on a long changelist with thousand of files. Is there a way to list only the ones that fit on my search?

Answer (score 1):

Use `p4 filelog` and grep for the desired action, e.g.:

```
C:\Perforce\test\merge>p4 filelog @=200 | grep "edit from"
... ... edit from //stream/main/merge/foo.txt#3
```

Note that "edit from" is the only resolve action that's guaranteed to be "manual" -- both "copy" and "ignore" can be either manual or automatic (they'll be automatic if only one leg of the merge has diffs, but can also be manually selected to override one or the other).

Comment: thanks, it worked but with a small change: p4 filelog ...@=200 | grep "\\(ignored\|edit from\\)"